# Excel pivot table - missing fields

Tags: microsoft-excel

OK - I've inherited a spreadsheet with a pivot table

I can trace all the pivot table fields to the headings in another worksheet, except one of them. There is a field shown in the list I can't find in any worksheet. HOw do I go about finding where the field data is.

Does seem to be any hidden column ot worksheets that might hold it.

Reason for asking is - insupplying new data this field has a whole heap more values and I don't know where they are coming from. They are playing havoc with the Pivot tables

Comment: Just noticed the Pivot table tools - lists the field as an "Active Field" is that the clue?

Comment: is it a calculated summary field?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there is a connection to an external data source.   Go to your ribbon, Data tab, select Connections.   In the dialog box it will list all connections to external data sources, and if you click on one, it will tell you where the connection is used.

Mike